# overriding retain and release methods in my own class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I want to override a retain and release methods in my class MapsLocationView in order to understand where i'm getting an extra release. Please help me do it in proper way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do release-retain investigation for me was:

```
'MapsLocationView.h'
@interface MapsLocationView : UIView {
    int releaseCount;
}

'MapsLocationView.m'
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    releaseCount = 0;
}

-(id)retain {
    NSLog(@"retain count+++:%d", [self retainCount]);
    return [super retain];
}

- (oneway void)release {
    releaseCount++;
    NSLog(@"releaseCount---:%d", releaseCount);
    [super release];
}
```

I also found that if you click on the method by right mouse button you can jump to its definition :)

Answer (score 6):

It's just a case of doing what you do everywhere else in Objective-C.

```
- (oneway void)release;
{
    [super release];
}

- (id)retain;
{
    return [super retain];
}
```

Comment: Your answer is completely correct but if you don't mind I want to answer my own question with a bit more information, thanks

Answer (score 1):

this would not be the proper way, you should use the leaks instrument or code analyser to find where the extra release is coming from

Comment: the point is that the extra release occurs 1 of 100 times...and it would be a hard work doing it in Leaks. A single breakpoint will help me...I hope :)

Comment: retain and release are methods from NSObject protocol, if you add - (id)retain to your class it should get called. you should increment the retain count and return self

Comment: or just return [super retain];